# Java string: character replacing in sentence

Tags: java, string, replace, char

"This is institute of insurance and insu."
How do I replace the first three character of institute with JSS in this sentence?
Need to display like this: "This is JSStitute of insurance and insu."

Answer (score 2):

Use string replace function

```
 String sentence = "This is institute of insurance and insu.";
 sentence = sentence.replace("institute", "JSStitute");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "This is institute of insurance and insu.".replaceFirst("ins", "JSS");
```